# unable to resolve host error with AWS Mobile Analytics on Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, host, amazon-mobile-analytics

I am trying to implement the starter code for AWS Mobile Analytics got from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/analytics.html

I have everything setup along with Internet permission in manifest but I am still getting this error after all debugging and troubleshooting.

```
02-27 17:40:38.403  25639-25830/com.bluecolony.watchappstore I/AmazonHttpClient﹕ Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve host "mobileanalytics.us-east-1.": No address associated with hostname
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "mobileanalytics.us-east-1.": No address associated with hostname
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:400)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:243)
        at com.amazonaws.services.mobileanalytics.AmazonMobileAnalyticsClient.invoke(AmazonMobileAnalyticsClient.java:313)
        at com.amazonaws.services.mobileanalytics.AmazonMobileAnalyticsClient.putEvents(AmazonMobileAnalyticsClient.java:258)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.amazonmobileanalytics.internal.delivery.DefaultDeliveryClient.submitEvents(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.amazonmobileanalytics.internal.delivery.DefaultDeliveryClient.access$600(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.amazonmobileanalytics.internal.delivery.DefaultDeliveryClient$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
        at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
```

```
com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        at com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:400)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:243)
        at com.amazonaws.services.mobileanalytics.AmazonMobileAnalyticsClient.invoke(AmazonMobileAnalyticsClient.java:313)
        at com.amazonaws.services.mobileanalytics.AmazonMobileAnalyticsClient.putEvents(AmazonMobileAnalyticsClient.java:258)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.amazonmobileanalytics.internal.delivery.DefaultDeliveryClient.submitEvents(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.amazonmobileanalytics.internal.delivery.DefaultDeliveryClient.access$600(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.amazonmobileanalytics.internal.delivery.DefaultDeliveryClient$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I have tried using ConnectivityManager and InetAddress.getByName("google.com").isReachable(3) to confirm that my code is able to access internet.

My assumption so far is that somehow hostname which is called is wrong. it should be "mobileanalytics.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" instead of "mobileanalytics.us-east-1." . Otherwise it can be a firewall issue or with https , which I have to explore further. I am connected with wifi on mobile.

Any pointers to help ?

Comment: Sorry about the trouble. We are aware of this issue and are working on the bug fix. Stay tuned.

Comment: Please check out the latest release v2.1.10 http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/3841134019807789

Comment: Thanks @Yangfan for the response. I will definitely try it out tomorrow and will update here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was a known bug with the AWS Mobile SDK v2.1.9.

Reading through @Yangfan's comment looks like this has been addressed in version 2.1.10

http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/3841134019807789